# Second Covariant Derivative Identity

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

My question is simple. Let $X^{\mu\nu}$ be a rank-2 tensor, and $\nabla_\mu$ be the metric compatible, torsion-free, covariant derivative. Does the identity $(\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu) X^{\mu\nu}=0$ holds ? My proof goes like this

1. Write the definition of the Riemann $(\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu) X^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{2}(R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\mu}X^{\lambda\nu}+R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\nu}X^{\mu\lambda})$.
2. Rename the indices $\mu\leftrightarrow\nu$ in the first term on the right, and use the antysymmetry $R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\nu}=-R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\mu}$ of the Riemann tensor, to get $(\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu) X^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{2}(-R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\nu}X^{\lambda\mu}+R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\nu}X^{\mu\lambda})$.
3. Introduce the *symmetric* Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\lambda}:=R_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{\phantom{\mu\nu\lambda}\nu}$, to get finally $(\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu)X^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}R_{\mu\lambda}(X^{\lambda\mu}-X^{\mu\lambda})$
4. That last term is the contraction of $R_{\mu\lambda}$ (*symmetric*) and $X^{\lambda\mu}-X^{\mu\lambda}$ (*anti-symmetric*), therefore vanishes.

This seems to be true for any $X^{\mu\nu}$, but the result seems quite strong, and I've never seen it anywhere.

Anybody can confirm and/or see a mistake in my reasoning ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. Here's another way to see it: Decompose $X^{\mu\nu}=A^{\mu\nu}+B^{\mu\nu}$ into its symmetric and skew symmetric parts $A^{\mu\nu}$ and $B^{\mu\nu}$, respectively.  For your 4th reason, $(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu)A^{\mu\nu}=0$.  The fact $(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu)B^{\mu\nu}=0$ follows from the fact $\delta^2=0$, where $\delta$ is the divergence on differential forms; this is the dual of the identity $d^2=0$.  More precisely,
$$ (\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu)B^{\mu\nu}=-2\nabla^\nu\nabla^\mu B_{\mu\nu} = -2\delta^2B = 0 . $$
(I raised and lowered indices just to emphasize that $\delta$ is the divergence.)

Comment: I am not really familiar with Einstein notation, when you write $(\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-\nabla_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu})A^{\mu\nu}$, is that the same as $\sum_{\mu\nu}(\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-\nabla_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu})A^{\mu\nu}$? Because this should be zero anyway since, in each factor, we are differentiating a function ($A^{\mu\nu}$) with respect to coordinate vector fields right? $\sum(\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-\nabla_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu})A^{\mu\nu}=\sum(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu})A^{\mu\nu}=\sum[\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}]A^{\mu\nu}=0$

Comment: I am using [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation).  This means that my notation does mean the sum over both $\mu$ and $\nu$, but that $\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta A^{\mu\nu}$ means the second covariant derivative of the $(2,0)$-tensor $A^{\mu\nu}$.  The vanishing of $(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu -\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu)A^{\mu\nu}$ is using this summation and symmetry (which is secretly used in your first equality to cancel Christoffel symbols).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:It turns I missunderstood the OP and I answered a totaly different question

Thw question I answered is: given a rank-2 tensor A
and two vector fields $\partial_{\mu}$ and $\partial_{\nu}$,
whether or not the identity concerning second
covariant derivatives of $A$ holds
$$(\nabla^2_{\mu,\nu}-\nabla^2_{\nu,\mu})A=0$$
I don't think this holds.
I take any two vector fields $V,\ W$
and a special case for the tensor $A$.
The second covariant derivative of a tensor $A$ is given by the formula
$$
\nabla^2_{V,W}A=\nabla_V(\nabla_WA)-\nabla_{\nabla_VW}A
$$
I give an example where $A$ is the tensor product of two vector fields.
The covariant derivative follows a Leibniz rule with tensor products, 
thus we calculate
\begin{align*}
    \nabla^2_{V,W}X\otimes Y
        &= \nabla_V(\nabla_W(X\otimes Y))-\nabla_{\nabla_VW}(X\otimes Y)\\
    &= \nabla_V(\nabla_WX\otimes Y+X\otimes \nabla_WY)
        -\nabla_{\nabla_VW}X\otimes Y -X\otimes \nabla_{\nabla_VW}Y\\
    &= \nabla_V\nabla_WX\otimes Y + \nabla_WX\otimes \nabla_VY\\
    &\hspace{5mm}+\nabla_VX\otimes \nabla_WY +X\otimes \nabla_V\nabla_WY \\
    &\hspace{5mm}-\nabla_{\nabla_VW}X\otimes Y
        -X\otimes\nabla_{\nabla_VW}Y
\end{align*}
Therefore, after some cancelations,
$(\nabla^2_{V,W}-\nabla^2_{W,V})X\otimes Y$ becomes
\begin{align*}
    (\nabla^2_{V,W}&-\nabla^2_{W,V})X\otimes Y=\\
    &=\nabla_V\nabla_WX\otimes Y -\nabla_W\nabla_VX\otimes Y 
        -\nabla_{\nabla_VW}X\otimes Y+\nabla_{\nabla_WV}X\otimes Y\\
    & \hspace{5mm}+X\otimes \nabla_V\nabla_WY -X\otimes \nabla_W\nabla_VY
        -X\otimes\nabla_{\nabla_VW}Y +X\otimes\nabla_{\nabla_WV}Y\\
    &=(R_{V,W}X)\otimes Y + X\otimes (R_{V,W}Y)
\end{align*}

Where in the last equality, we used the definition of Riemann curvature
with the fact that $\nabla_VW-\nabla_WV=[V,W]$.
Then, for the simple case of the symmetric rank 2 tensor tensor
$X\otimes X$, for some vector field $X$, we have that
\begin{align*}
    (\nabla^2_{V,W} - \nabla^2_{W,V})X\otimes X=0 \text{ iff}\\
    (R_{V,W}X)\otimes X + X\otimes (R_{V,W}X)=0 \text{ iff}\\
    \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        R_{V,W}X=X &  \text{and}\\
        R_{V,W}X=-X & 
    \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
But this is clearly impossible for $X\neq0$, thus
$(\nabla^2_{V,W}-\nabla^2_{W,V})X\otimes X$ cannot be zero

Let me know if you notice something I might not have, thanks in advance

Comment: The OP is not asking that $(\nabla_{\mu,\nu}^2-\nabla_{\nu,\mu}^2)A=0$ --- which is a statement about the vanishing of rank-2 tensor field --- but rather whether the complete contraction vanishes --- which is a statement about the vanishing of a scalar function, the one you wrote in your comment to my answer.  That the OP intends Einstein summation notation is indicated by the definition of the Ricci tensor given in Point 3.

Comment: I think I get it now, so the OP is asking about the contraction of a $(2,2)$ tensor that is defined using the second covariant derivatives of $A$. I examined the $(2,2)$ tensor itself. Thank you! Mybe I should delete the answer?